# Listen to Orientation State in Flutter; before & after rotation

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

`OrientationBuilder` reports the orientation change after the full transformation has taken place, then the rebuild occurs after that.

Is there a way to act before the orientation initiates? I am not trying to pre-empt the rotation, but make changes simutaneously, not after.

The goal:

1. Device is rotated.
2. Detect this and rebuild UI to show overlay.
3. Flutter performs its own tranformation, rotating UI to new orientation.
4. After fixed time period simply rebuild to hide overlay.

The challenge, how to fulfil point 2 before 3 occurs?

Comment: No, this is not feasible. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to put a veil over the the screen as it transforms/rotates, as it looks pretty bad. Imagine when you resize an app on iPadOS, it blurs the content as it rescales. Simple effect, but don't see how I can achieve it without being able to apply this at the same time as the transform (not after).

Comment: Try using MediaQuery, not sure if it'll work though.

Comment: I think that reaches the same issue though. Not being able to grab that info and rebuild before the orientation changes.

Comment: @RémiRousselet How did you determine that this is not feasible?

Comment: OrientationBuilder is based on LayoutBuilder, not MediaQuery. The orientation could technically change without the screen size changing

Answer (score 20):

Yes, you *can* get the orientation change **earlier** using `WidgetsBindingObserver` by overriding [`didChangeMetrics`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didChangeMetrics.html).

### How to use `didChangeMetrics`

You can simply mixin `WidgetBindingObserver` in a [`State` implementation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) of a stateful widget:

```dart
class _FooState extends State with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    // This will be triggered by changes in orientation.
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

### Determining the orientation

Orientation is determined by the aspect ratio of the available size. This means that you can get the orientation in `didChangeMetrics` using the following code:

```dart
final orientation = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize
    .aspectRatio > 1 ? Orientation.landscape : Orientation.portrait;
```

## Example

I have constructed an example `StatefulWidget` that compares the `OrientationBuilder` callback to `didChangeMetrics`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(OrientationListener());
}

class OrientationListener extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OrientationListenerState createState() => _OrientationListenerState();
}

class _OrientationListenerState extends State<OrientationListener>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    print('$WidgetsBindingObserver metrics changed ${DateTime.now()}: '
        '${WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize.aspectRatio > 1 ? Orientation.landscape : Orientation.portrait}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window),
      child: OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (context, orientation) {
          print('$OrientationBuilder rebuild ${DateTime.now()}: $orientation');

          return Container();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Results

Running this example shows the following times for the two functions:

```
WidgetsBindingObserver metrics changed 2020-08-22 14:47:01.690172: Orientation.portrait
WidgetsBindingObserver metrics changed 2020-08-22 14:47:01.706574: Orientation.landscape
OrientationBuilder rebuild 2020-08-22 14:47:01.760589: Orientation.landscape
WidgetsBindingObserver metrics changed 2020-08-22 14:47:06.537083: Orientation.landscape
WidgetsBindingObserver metrics changed 2020-08-22 14:47:06.549545: Orientation.portrait
OrientationBuilder rebuild 2020-08-22 14:47:06.603859: Orientation.portrait
WidgetsBindingObserver metrics changed 2020-08-22 14:47:10.423787: Orientation.portrait
WidgetsBindingObserver metrics changed 2020-08-22 14:47:10.442866: Orientation.landscape
OrientationBuilder rebuild 2020-08-22 14:47:10.501729: Orientation.landscape
WidgetsBindingObserver metrics changed 2020-08-22 14:47:13.639545: Orientation.landscape
WidgetsBindingObserver metrics changed 2020-08-22 14:47:13.658906: Orientation.landscape
WidgetsBindingObserver metrics changed 2020-08-22 14:47:13.672025: Orientation.portrait
OrientationBuilder rebuild 2020-08-22 14:47:13.730771: Orientation.portrait
```

So in my case, the difference in detection was about `0.06` seconds.

#### Observations

As you can see from above, the difference is insignificant (I would say). So I am not even sure if this will be useful to you.

Moreover, I have observed that the `OrientationBuilder` callback is actually called **at the start** of the device rotation - at least on my Android emulator. This would mean that you can rebuild your UI before the rotation happens.

---

I hope this was somehow helpful to you :)

Comment: Really appreciate your detailed breakdown here, however despite registering at the start of the rotation, the rebuild doesn't actually occur/complete until after the rotation finishes. E.g. Add a colour to your `Container`. In `didChangeMetrics` `setState` to change a bool `isRotating = true`. For the sake of the test, I just set it back to false with a `Timer` after 1-2 seconds. Change the colour using the bool, but the colour doesn't change until after the rotation.

Comment: @JoshKahane  Yes, that is right :) This is because the build will happen at the same time as the `OrientationBuilder` one. You can simply not paint at that time it seems (:

Comment: It was really helpfull for my task. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in this link, there is no "natural" way to do what you want: 
 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16322

Try to make something using this:

1. Lock the orientation: https://dev.to/mightytechno/how-to-change-screen-orientation-in-flutter-32c1
2. Listen to device rotation changes with this package (since the orientation will not change): https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation
3. Make your customization
4. Set the new orientation using the link from step 1

You may try animated container for a better effect, but you would need to handle all the screen position and rotation manually before set the new orientation:

 https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Something you might want to try is writing a platform channel method to get the sensor data from the accelerometer and then feed it to something like Transform.rotate().